# Z~U[0,1] and X=f(Z) and f is:

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

[image: This is f(Z)]

I have found the f(z):
[image]

Now, I need to find pdf of X. And I can see that 0< f(Z)=X<1, I don't know how I am going to get f(X), I just can see that f(X)=0 when X<0 and x>1, but I can see a way to get it in  0< X< 1

Comment: You seem to be using $f$ and $F$ in rather confusing ways.

Comment: One approach might be to find $\Pr(X \le x)$ and then differentiate.  You may have different expressions depending on whether $x$ is less than or greater than $\frac12$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us translate the graph in terms of conditional distributions:

- Conditionally on $0\lt Z\lt\frac3{10}$, $X$ is uniform on $(0,1)$, with density $g=\mathbf 1_{(0,1)}$.
- Conditionally on $\frac3{10}\lt Z\lt\frac6{10}$, $X$ is uniform on $(\frac12,1)$, with density $h=2\mathbf 1_{(1/2,1)}$.
- Conditionally on $\frac6{10}\lt Z\lt1$, $X$ is uniform on $(\frac12,1)$, with density $h$.

These cases happen with respective probabilities $a$, $a$ and $b$, where $a=\frac3{10}$ and $b=\frac4{10}$ hence the density of $X$ is $$ag+ah+bh=\frac3{10}\mathbf 1_{(0,1/2)}+\frac{17}{10}\mathbf 1_{(1/2,1)}.$$